# How many models of 3D truck

Tags: 3d, blender

I want to model your 3D tractor. But I don't have dimensions in my hand. How do my models. To make a real volvo. I am using blender

Comment: ...I have no idea what you're asking, but it definitely isn't on-topic. Please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it seems like you're trying to model a truck or tractor? If so, this isn't really the place to ask for how to model. If you need help with modeling, I suggest watching some tutorials and finding reference images for what you're modeling.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).